# How to gain fast performance on MySQL using TEXT type field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, google-maps

I am doing one Gmap Application has one form and one table.
I have some performance issues.
Following are what I have.

> **Table: my_routes**

```
id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(255)
coordinates MEDIUMTEXT
```

> **My Form:**

```
<form action="save.php">
<div id="map">GMap Here</div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" />
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="coordinates" />
<input type="submit" name="btnsave"/>
</form>
```

I am adding new markers and it will give me all the direction coordinates which I will store in hidden field "coordinates"

this field contains large number of coordinates
e.g.

```
"46.963530000000006,7.950190000000001;46.96359,7.950360000000001;46.963640000000005,7.95049;46.963680000000004,7.95063;46.96374,7.9507900000000005;46.96378000000001,7.950950000000001;46.963800000000006,7.95105;46.96381,7.95117;46.96381,7.951280000000001;46.96378000000001,7.951480000000001;46.96374,7.951650000000001;46.96367,7.9519400000000005;46.963640000000005,7.952100000000001;46.96360000000001,7.952370000000001;46.96358,7.952580000000001;46.96356,7.95272;46.963550000000005,7.952870000000001;46.96356,7.952960000000001;46.96358,7.953050000000001;"
```

When i save the data it will save but take too much time to save and also when getting the data for modify purpose.

> **I have following settings on WAMP Server ( PHP )**

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
max_execution_time = 180
post_max_size = 128M
```

Can anyone help me how to deal with this issue?
What are the changes or suggestions to gain good performance for my GMap form?

Welcome, suggestions

Comment: for which purposes do you store these coordinates? Which MySQL-version? Define "too much time"

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use DECIMAL data types for storing cordinates, and possible splitting data into two tables, for example -

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE coordinates (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_fk int(11) NOT NULL,
  latitude decimal(10, 8) DEFAULT NULL,
  longitude decimal(10, 8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_coordinates_main_id FOREIGN KEY (id_fk)
  REFERENCES main (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: I have thing like you that separation of two tables.
But it is feasible because for that we need to do extra processing to get same result from JOIN Tables and put via SQL Queries.

Can we do such a thing with TEXT/MEDIUMTEXT data-type?
We cannot get benefits from above data type?

Comment: You could use one table, but as you see - `name` values will be repeated many times. That is because I splitted the data. I just used two tables to normalize data.